# charAt error "char cannot be converted to string"

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to use the following code so that given a string, give the length of the longest contiguous subsequence of the same character. I am getting the error "incompatible types: char cannot be converted to java.lang.String". I have commented where the error is being found below.

```
public class Test {
    public int longestRep(String str)
    {
        int currLen = 1;
        String currLet = "";
        String maxLet = "";
        int maxCount = 0;
        int currPos = 0;
        int strLen = str.length();
        for(currPos = 0; currPos < strLen; currPos++)
        {
            currLet = str.charAt(currPos); //error is on this line
            if(currLet = str.charAt(currPos+1))
            {
                currLen++;
            }
            else
            {
                if(currLen > maxLen)
                {
                    maxLen = currLen;
                    maxLet = currLet;
                    currLen = 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        longestRep("AaaaMmm");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's because a char can't be converted to a String - I'm not sure what there is to not understand.

Comment: sorry about that, I'm a newbie to Java and am still learning syntax etc...

Comment: You could change `String currLet = "";` to `char currLet = ' ';` and `String == String` is not how `String` comparison works in Java anyway...

Comment: I have used this solution @MadProgrammer , but now I have an error on the next line saying "incompatible types: char cannot be converted to boolean"

Comment: @Hugo That's because `if(currLet = str.charAt(currPos+1))` - `=` is an assignment, not a comparison, you are trying to assign the value of `str.charAt(currPos+1)` to `currLet` which results in a `char`, but `if` is looking for a `boolean` result ...

Comment: Make sure you test your program on this string: `"aaazzzzz"`.  The way you've written it, I don't think it will work, and it will be instructive to go through and figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `currLet = str.charAt(currPos);` A `String` value can't be assigned to a `char`, they are different types, apples and oranges
- `if (currLet = str.charAt(currPos + 1)) {` is actually an assignment (make `currLet` equal to the value of `str.charAt(currPos + 1)`)
- `if (currLen > maxLen) {` - `maxLen` is undefined
- You never `return` anything from the method...

Try changing:

- `String currLet = "";` to something more like `char currLet = '\0';` and `String maxLet = "";` to `char maxLet = '\0';`
- `if (currLet = str.charAt(currPos + 1)) {` to something like `if (currLet == str.charAt(currPos + 1)) {`
- Add `int maxLen = 0` to your variable declerations (may be under `int maxCount = 0`)

Now, based on your example code, `public int longestRep(String str) {` will need to be `public static int longestRep(String str) {` in order for you to call from you `main` method...

Comment: This fixed all my errors, except I am unsure now where to return the value I need, and which variable I need to return

Comment: My "guess" is you want to `return` `maxLen`, based on the fact that you method is declared as returning an `int`.  ps- You will get a runtime exception, so be prepared for some debugging.

Comment: @Hugo Also, it will do you no good to return `maxLen` if you throw away the result when you call your method.  Make sure you assign the result to something, or do something else with it, when you call `longestRep`.

Comment: Thanks @MadProgrammer now the only error I have is index out of range in the second line of the for loop. What code should I use to avoid going out of range for the charAt? Thanks so much for all your help.

Comment: @Hugo Maybe something like `for (currPos = 0; currPos < strLen - 1; currPos++) {`.  You will have to do another check for `if (currLen > maxLen) {` in case the last character is part of the sequence which is longer then anything else...

Answer (score 10):

`String.charAt(int)` returns a character. But `currLet` is of type `String`, so you can't assign a character. Use `currLet = Character.toString(str.charAt(currPos));` instead.

Comment: Thanks so much for that! Now I seem to have the same error on the very next line... Do I use the same solution for this?

Comment: @Paul This is not how `String` comparison works in Java.  You've thrown the OP out of the pot and into the fire...

Comment: @MadProgrammer who is comparing anything? this is just a solution for converting a character into a string.

Comment: @Paul The next `if` statement. `if(currLet = str.charAt(currPos+1))`, which is where your "example" code comes from...

Comment: @MadProgrammer thats another type of error... . i only provided a soution to the typeissue. and never said anything different.

Comment: Mind you, it's an assignment, not a comparison anyway, but you've just lead the op from one problem to another...

Answer (score 5):

As the compiler said, you can't convert a `char` to a `String`.  If you have a `char` and you really want to convert it to a `String` of length 1, this will work:

```
String s = String.valueOf(c);
```

or

```
String s = Character.toString(c);
```

However, if the character you're working with was obtained by `charAt`, another solution is to get rid of `charAt` and use `substring` to return a string of length 1:

```
currLet = str.substring(currPos, currPos + 1);
```

Answer (score 3):

### Easy way to convert Char to String

Add an empty String to the start of expression, because adding char and  String results into String.

**Convert one char**  `"" + 'a'`
**Convert multiple chars**  `"" + 'a' + 'b'`

Converting multiple chars works because `"" + 'a'` is evaluated first.
If the `""` were at the end instead you would get `"195"`

> Remember that Java language guarantees ([Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/#15.7), Java SE 7 Edition, section 15.12.4.2) that all arguments are evaluated from left to right (unlike some other languages, where the order of evaluation is undefined)